# AngularJS show two views/templates on screen

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile, angularjs-directive, touch

I'm working on an angular powered mobile app and what I need to implement is a view, which shows halves of two separate views. User can then switch to any of them by swiping up/down. Any tips how to start with this thing ? I'm attaching an image showing what I mean :

[image]

Any tips are welcome since I don't have too much experience with angular itself.

Answer (score 2):

Use ui-router.

```
<div showHalfViews>
    <div ui-view="topView"></div>
    <div ui-view="bottomView"></div>
</div>
```

Then create the `showHalfViews` directive, which will find its two child elements and add the required functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at ui-router (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). It supports multiple and named views in the same page I think.